# How can I select data for a chart based on a dropdown?

Tags: altair

I have a dataframe for which I want to sub-select a set of rows based on a dropdown.  So Given the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

cars = pd.melt(data.cars(), ['Horsepower', 'Origin', 'Name', 'Year'])
cars.head()

select_box = alt.binding_select(options=list(cars['variable'].unique()))
selection = alt.selection_single(name='d_axis', fields=['variable'], bind=select_box)

alt.Chart(cars).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='value',
    color='Origin',
    tooltip='Name'
).add_selection(
    selection
).transform_filter(
    selection
)
```

Instead of changing the X values, I want to only select cars where Origin is 'USA'.
So in effect something where

```
alt.Chart(cars).mark_point().encode(
```

becomes:

```
alt.Chart(cars[cars['Origin'] == selection]).mark_point().encode(
```

Thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tie the selection to the field you want to filter:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

cars = data.cars()

select_box = alt.binding_select(options=list(cars['Origin'].unique()))
selection = alt.selection_single(fields=['Origin'], bind=select_box)

alt.Chart(cars).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon'
).add_selection(
    selection
).transform_filter(
    selection
)
```

[image]